# Math chracters \prime, active prime ('), *, \circ printing double superscript position in xelatex

Tags: math-mode, xetex, fontspec, math-fonts, mathcode

I am trying to redefine the math characters from `STIX Two Math` otf font, i successfully redefine all characters in `xelatex` through `\Umathchardef` command.

I am facing the issue for `\prime`, active prime `(')`, `*` and `\circ` symbols, those characters positions are printed as double superscript position, because of font have only superscript position.

how to redefine the characters to get the actual output
[normal superscript for `\prime` and  `'` (should produce the same output of \prime) and `*`,  `\circ`]

Thanks in advance

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\StixTwoMath{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[NFSSFamily=stixtwomath]

\DeclareSymbolFont{stixmath}{TU}{stixtwomath}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{*}{\mathbin}{stixmath}{"002A} % \ast
\Umathchardef\prime "0 \csname symstixmath\endcsname"2032
\Umathchardef\circ "2 \csname symstixmath\endcsname"2218

\begin{document}

$a'_{i}$  $a^\prime_{i}$ $a\prime$ 

\medskip

$\rho^*$  $\rho*$ \qquad $a^*$  $a*$

\medskip

$\chi^{\circ}$  $\chi {\circ}$ \qquad $a^\circ$  $a\circ$

\end{document}
```

Comment: you want a stix prime on computer modern letters? Why not use `unicode-math` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, unicode-math.sty producing correct output, but i am trying to redefine math characters without unicode-math.sty,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i am trying to use two fonts for math characters

Comment: Are you quite sure about `\circ`?  It looks like a superscript on `\chi`, but that's because of that letter's shape.  On "a", it's properly positioned.

Comment: @barbara beeton, yes but for \prime, and * have different position

Comment: I ask as as far as I can tell the adjustment is being made automatically by the engine when doing opentype math layout but not if as here the main math font is a classic tex tfm font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am using Minion for base and math font, if minion does not have the symbols, the characters will be sourced from stix font. Before that i tried with minion font for these characters, i got the same result , so i tried with stix font

Comment: Minion isn't  Math font either. You would find it much easier to use unicode-math with stix 2 as main font so  opentype layout used, then use the Range feature to specify Minion  letters.